# How can I avoid repeatedly casting to a descendant interface type?

Tags: delphi, frameworks

I'm making a framework (for internal use only) that has common code among 3 o 4 delphi database CRUD applications..

A common object of mi framework is a TContext,

```
TContext = class (IContext)
  function DB: IDatabase;
  function CurrentSettings: ISettings;
  ..
 end;
```

that is passed to the initialization method of lots of other objects.. example (this will be application code):

```
 TCustomer.Initialize(Context: IContext)
 TProjectList.Initialize(Context: IContext)
 ..
```

Every application has some specific context functions (that only will be called from application code):

```
 IApp1Context = interface (IContext)
   procedure DoSomethingSpecificToApp1;
   procedure DoOtherThing;
   ..
 end;
```

So when I create a Context, Im creating a IApp1Context, and sending it to the initialization methods.. from the framework code everything is fine, the problem is that from the application code I'm constantly casting from IContext to IApp1Context to access the specific 
App1 functions.. so all my application code looks like (and its a lot of code like this):

```
 (FContext as IApp1Context).DoSomethingSpecificToApp1
 (FContext as IApp1Context).DoOtherThing;
 ..
```

The thing is clearly usable, but doesnt reads well in my opinion. Maybe I'm exaggerating; is there is a clever design technique for this situation that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a temporary variable. Assign it once at the start of the method, and then use it where you need it.

```
var
  AppContext: IApp1Context;
begin
  AppContext := FContext as IApp1Context;

  AppContext.DoSomethingSpecificToApp1;
  AppContext.DoOtherThing;
end;
```

Or, since it looks like your `IContext` object is a field of an object, make your `IApp1Context` variable be a field of the same object. It could even replace the `IContext` field since `IApp1Context` already exposes everything the `IContext` does.

```
procedure TCustomer.Initialize(const Context: IContext);
begin
  FContext := Context;
  FAppContext := FContext as IApp1Context;
  // ...
end;
```

Comment: If I'm using a temporary variable I should declare and assign it at every method I use IApp1Context.. still doesnt seams 100% clean to me from a framework design point of view (this may be subjective).. look at my proposed solution what do you think? thanks

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of this possible solution using generics?

pro: no casting necesary
down: the generic invades almost every interface and class of the framework, making it more complicated..

```
// framework //
type
  IContext = interface
    function DB;
    ..
  end;

  TContext = class (TInterfaedObject, IContext)
    function DB;
    ..
  end;

  IBusinessObj<T: IContext> = interface
    procedure Initialize(AContext: T);
  end;

  TBusinessObj<T: IContext> = class (TInterfacedObject, IBusinessObj<T>)
  protected
    FContext: T;
  public
    procedure Initialize(Context: T); virtual;
  end;

procedure TBusnessObj<T>.Initialize(Context: T);
begin
  FContext := Context;

  FContext.DB.Connect;
end;

// application //
type
  IApp1Context = interface (IContext)
    procedure DoSomethingElse;
    ..
  end;

  TApp1Context = class(TContext, IContext, IApp1Context)
    function DB;
    procedure DoSomethingElse;
  end;

  TCustomer = class(TBusinessObj<IApp1Context>)
  public
    procedure Initialize(AContext: IApp1Context); override;
  end;

procedure Start;
var
  C: IBusinessObj<IApp1Context>;
begin
  C := TCustomer.Create;
  C.Initializate(TApp1Context.Create);
  ..
end;

procedure TCustomer.Initialize(AContext: IApp1Context);
begin
  inherited;

  FContext.DoSomethingElse // here I can use FContext as a IApp1Context.. 
end;
```

Comment please, Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a good scenario for generics.  My brain wants to percolate around class references a bit too, because it seems like there's some areas where a factory pattern could be useful.  Then again, generics could help there too.  At any rate, your code looks sane.

Answer (score 1):

You could also give your class a private function `AppContext` defined like this:

```
function AppContext : IApp1Context;

begin
Result := FContext as IApp1Context;
end;
```

This avoids the additional variable declaration and keeps the cast local. From client code you can just write:

```
AppContext.DoSomethingSpecificToApp1;
AppContext.DoOtherThing
```

Comment: Better yet, if you are free in the organization of interfaces, you could add such method to icontext, since otherwise you had to get the class from the reference (using componentreference) or so.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I don't get your comment. As far as I understood the question, `IContext` is defined within the framework and does not know about the application-specific interfaces. And letting the base type know about all available subtypes is not a good idea IMHO.